# Is it possible to open VIM not in full screen?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

Sometimes I need to edit a small config file and return to my terminal workflow.
Opening VIM by default will cover the entire screen, just for a small change.

Is there any option to open vim, not in fullscreen?
If not, is there any terminal text editor that can do that?

Comment: You can open vim as a terminal editor - for me at least, `vim` opens in the terminal, whereas `gvim` opens in a new window

Comment: As @mm_sz said, Tmux or Screen might be helpful.  Personally, if I have to make a small simple change and I want to be able to see the terminal context while I do it, I sometimes use Ed or Sed.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Vim doesn't provide any way to modify your terminal window. But you can use terminal emulators like [Tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) for multi-window support. And don't forget that you can do `:vert term` in Vim to split your window, but with some limited possibilities